# how do I call a function inside an event listener?

Tags: addeventlistener

I use the codes to invoke a click event in a button. I got an uncaught type error,

```
let inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn")

inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
console.log("Button clicked from addEventListener")
```

})

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it inside an html script? Is the html script before or after the html code? Exactly what error do you got?

Comment: The script tag is before the button tag. The error message is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: Try declaring the script at the end of the html code. The error may be that the script executes before the html elements are created, so it returns null.

Comment: I use an extrenal link in the body tag in the html file to the js file. <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="index.js"></script>
        <input type="text" id="input-el">
        <button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Put the script at the end of the body, and try again, it should work.